# How to add SSZipArchive (or any other zipping library) to swift project ios 7.1 manually? There is no module as SSZipArchive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, zip, ssziparchive

I have gone through the git page of [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) as of how to add it to the project manually. But the error keeps popping up as "There is no module SSZipArchive" when "import SSZipArchive".

Please tell me the steps to add SSZipArchive manually to a project from git.

Comment: Instead of adding manually try using https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: @Yogesh Cocoapods are not supported in ios 7.1 right?

Comment: Xcode 7.1 supports Cocoapods

Comment: I am using ios version 7.1 @Yogesh

Comment: https://github.com/devxoul/CocoaSeeds may help to support dependencies in a Swift project on iOS7.